# How to check url exists or not on wp7 apps?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to load a image for my apps.
I know the exact URL that I need to acquire the image. How to check URL exists or not ?

Comment: get the response code from the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use something like this.

```
bool result = false;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url);
            if (stream != null)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Any exception will returns false.
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
```

As you are using WP7, you may need to look the async versions.

Source : http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-check-remote-file-exists-using-c/